# Can leveraging only tense convey that some action is no longer relevant?

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

There are two sentences I myself come up with:

> 1. I haven't checked my inbox for the last few days.
> 2. I didn't check my inbox for the last few days.

Is #2 grammatically correct and idiomatic? Does #2 imply that I didn't check, but I have already checked it (e.g. today). Does #1 imply that I haven't checked yet? Or is it ambiguous?

Comment: _I **didn't** check my inbox **for** the last few days_ is not grammatical— simple past tense should refer back to a particular action/event that happened in the past; the continuity of the action/event is conveyed better by the perfect tense as in 1.

Comment: @user405662 can the phrase be rewritten to make it sound grammatical with past simple? E.g. "I didn't check my inbox **in** the last few days" or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s possible for you to have checked your inbox at a different time if you use didn’t, but not with haven’t, since you specified today. The second one has already passed, so it’s possible that you’ve checked them now. While the first one is ongoing—you *really* haven’t seen a single email in your inbox up until now (for the last few days).

(But if you want to sound more polite, then use “haven’t.” You can’t just tell your friend who gave you a book, “I didn’t read it.” Rather, say, “I haven’t read it,” so you could say that “haven’t” is a little more opportunistic than “didn’t.” Same goes for your example.)